# Chromecast - Launch Media Via the CastMessageBus

Tags: javascript, ios, json, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a Custom Chromecast Receiver App. Is it possible to launch media via the [Cast Message Bus](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastMessageBus)? I'm aware that it's not the best practice and there is already a mechanism to launch media via the `GCKMediaControlChannel`

I'm using the https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer as a starting point.

I'm sending the text message (containing the Media Info JSON) via my sender like this:

`[_castServiceChannel sendTextMessage:mediaInfoJSON];`

The JSON is being received on the receiver and I am then trying to launch the media player like so:

`sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.loadVideo_(message);`

But I'm not initialising the media player properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that I couldn't launch the video because:

1. `loadVideo_()` was the wrong method, I should be using `load()`
2. The player was never initialised properly when receiving the cast messages.

My solution was to separate the `cast message bus` messages from the player. So in my `player.html`, I init the `cast message bus`. When I `receive JSON` of the media that I want to play, I init `player.js` from `player.html` like so:

```
//receive message to play -> pass media through
var player = document.getElementById('player');
new sampleplayer.CastPlayer(player).start();
```

then in

```
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.start = function() {
  this.load(JSON.parse(message));
};
```

Only thing that's a problem is that the `Media Manager` is never properly initialised in the `Cast Receiver app`. So this means that I can't capture RCU events properly. Any ideas why this could be happening?